# Using google's application as part of a patent

Tags: design-patent

I am thinking about constructing a device small part of which uses google's code/application that we all have in our android phones. I believe I should get the "OK" from google or there is no need? How can I proceed on situations like that?

Comment: Can you please add some clarity? Do you mean using some of Google’s code? If so you are asking a licensing question. Read the Android license for guidance.

Comment: Are you concerned about making a prototype or a product? Note that working prototypes are not needed to file a patent and not all details of a embodiment may need to be explained.

Comment: A prototype in order to become a product...What's the difference?

Comment: Are you intending to patent your device? I’m having trouble understanding what part of your question relates to patents.

Comment: I googled Android software license and found the following: https://developer.android.com/studio/terms

Comment: @Eric S I am thinking for patent it, only if it is legal, I mean to not having conflicts with google, otherwise not!

Comment: As I commented earlier, use of Googles software almost certainly is controlled by a license. License questions are off topic on this site. I’d try to read the license for the software you want to use. If the license isn’t clear, then asking permission is a very good idea.

Comment: There is an Android Enthusiast site on Stack Exchange which might be useful to you.